# Methodology behind moment generating function $E(e^{t(A-B)})$ for two independent and identically distributed random variables A and B

Tags: probability, statistics, exponentiation, moment-generating-functions

For independent and identically distributed random variables A and B which both share a moment generating function (mgf) of $M(t) = E(e^{tA}) = \frac{3-t}{e^t}$. The mgf of A - B is, [using methodology in the answers  from this thread:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2635731/let-x-and-y-be-independent-and-identically-distributed-random-variables-with)

$$E(e^{t(A-B)}) = E(e^{tA}e^{-tB})= E(e^{tA})E(e^{-tB}) = \frac{3-t}{e^t}\frac{3-(-t)}{e^(-t)} = \frac{3-t}{e{^t}}\frac{3+t}{e^{-t}} = (3-t)(3+t)$$

Here is different methodology, which I know is incorrect but I don't know why. I would assume it would be correct on the basis of $e^{p-q} = e^{p}/e^{q}$. Whilst this reaches the same incorrect answer in the linked OP, the methodology is different:

$$E(e^{t(A-B)}) = E(\frac{e^{tA}}{e^{tB}}) = \frac{E(e^{tA})}{E(e^{tB})} = \frac{\frac{3-t}{e^t}}{\frac{3-t}{e^t}} = 3$$

I am asking how I would disapprove the later methodology?

Comment: Note that $E[x]^{-1} \ne E[x^{-1}]$ just like $ E[x^2] \ne E[x]^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incorrect step is
$$E \left[\frac{e^{tA}}{e^{tB}}\right] \ne \frac{E [e^{tA}]}{E [e^{tB}]}$$

In general independence of $A$ and $B$ implies $E[f(A)g(B)]=E[f(A)] \cdot E[g(B)]$. Thus $E[f(A)/g(B)] = E[f(A)] \cdot E[1/g(B)]$ which is not $E[f(A)] / E[g(B)]$ because $E[1/g(B)] \ne 1/E[g(B)]$.